# formatting a date output

Tags: php, date

I've got an arry with dates.

```
print_r ($date[$i]);
```

will output sth. like:
2011-06-16

Is it possible to create an output like: 16.6.2011 ?
How would I do that?
have you got a reference?

Comment: PHP has a very fine manual. Please read it.

Comment: [5000+ exact and near duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=formatting+a+date+output+[php]). [Please use the search function before asking.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?

echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime( $date[$i] ) );

?>
```

Comment: That's not a valid format for strftime... If you're using strftime OP wants '%d.%n.%Y' or '%e.%n.%Y'

Comment: -1 This could add timezone disparities. It's also limited to the range of UNIX timestamps.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal it's not limited to the range of UNIX timestamps, strtotime can produce negative values and values greater than a 32 bit int. date can similarly handle those values. And how will the timezone affect it? the timezone is converted to UTC and back again.

Comment: @Jamie that does produce leading zeros on both day and month, which appears in the question that at the very least OP doesn't want leading zeros on month.

Comment: @Jacob: ["The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)". Granted it goes back earlier than a UNIX timestamp. Looking closer at the timezones I suppose there's no concern there.

Comment: Can I have my -1 back then please?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal my apologies. I just tried it out on my local machine, which is 64 bit as well, so is probably less likely to have issues. Interesting note...

Comment: @Jamie: No, you can't, because `DateTime` is still better: it uses a 64-bit integer internally, giving a date range from about from about 292 billion years ago to about 292 billion years in the future.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I think that was meant for Jamie.

Comment: @Jamie: Unsolicited personal attacks are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

you should find that this page has all the answers for you

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the date function to print it, using the strtotime function to first convert it to a Unix timestamp. Or you can use the DateTime functions like:

```
date_create($date[$i])->format('d.n.Y');
```

If you don't want leading 0's on your day, then you should use:

```
date_create($date[$i])->format('j.n.Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

use the php date() function

you can see a documentation about it here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

```
date('d.n.Y', strtotime($date[$i]));
```

There is a reference when you search in Google for "date" ;)

Comment: Your edit is invalid as well... the 2nd argument to date must be an integer (unix timestamp) you need strtotime.

Comment: Still -1 because now you're passing a string to `date()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have a date, but a string. Either manipulate the string with [the string manipulation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php), or parse and re-format the date string with [the date functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).